# Asynchronous call to server side function in google script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, pdf-generation

In my google script web app, I need to design a function that fetches the data from the webpage, pastes it into a google sheet, generates a pdf based on this google sheet, and then sends it by email to the user.
So far my program goes like this:

The function picks the data from the webpage, it calls a server-side function to update the values in the google sheet and send the pdf.

Html side:

```
function generateReport(){ 
    data=getDataFromThePage()
    google.script.run.updateTheSheetAndSendPdf(data)
}
```

Server side(Google App Script)

```
function updateTheSheetAndSendPdf(data){
    var reportSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(REPORT_ID).getSheetByName('report');

reportSheet.getRange(34,2,10,24).clearContent()

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for (param in data[i]){
        if (data[i][param].c!=null){
            reportSheet.getRange(data[i][param].c[0],data[i][param].c[1]).setValue(data[i][param].p)
            }
          }
}

 var email = data.user; 
 var subject = "your PDF extract";
 var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(REPORT_ID).getAs("application/pdf");

 blob.setName("yourReport.pdf");

 if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
   GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
     htmlBody: body,
     noReply:true,
     attachments:[blob]     
});  
}
```

The issue is that, for some reason, when i run the generateReport() function, the pdf i receive by email corresponds to the values PREVIOUSLY recorded in the google sheet.

It is only when I run generateReport() for the second time that the correct data finally gets into the pdf.

So I come to the conclusion that the function sendEmail runs "too early", before the google sheet is even updated

Would someone know how to make sure the google sheet values are updated BEFORE generating the pdf?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your script, it seems that you want to run ``generateAndSendPdf()`` after ``updateTheGoogleSheet()`` was finished. Is there the reason that you cannot include ``generateAndSendPdf()`` in ``updateTheGoogleSheet()``?

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, I've just tried as you suggested, and unfortunately I have the same result. It seems that as soon as the SpreadsheetApp is called to update the googlesheet, the program immediately goes to the next line and execute the pdf generation

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to understand correctly your situation, can you provide the script of GAS side?

Comment: I have edited my question with more detail on the server side function, hope it clarifies :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the function ``updateTheSheetAndSendPdf()``, can you put ``SpreadsheetApp.flush()`` after ``var subject = "your PDF extract";`` and try to run again? Document of ``flush()`` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush). And also, can you split the script to HTML side and GAS side? I think that the current script might confuse users who try to think of your solution. If this was not the direct solution, I'm sorry.

Comment: Excellent! the SpreadsheetApp.flush() function works perfectly. Thank you very much Tanaike, I will post the answer soon

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you accept your answer by yourself? By this, other users can see your question as the resolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine by adding SpreadsheetApp.flush() before generating the pdf blob. It "expedites" the update of the google sheet, so that the latest values are used to generate the pdf. Thank you to Tanaike for this solution.

Server side (html side remains the same):

```
function updateTheSheetAndSendPdf(data){
var reportSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(REPORT_ID).getSheetByName('report');

reportSheet.getRange(34,2,10,24).clearContent()

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for (param in data[i]){
        if (data[i][param].c!=null){
            reportSheet.getRange(data[i][param].c[0],data[i][param].c[1]).setValue(data[i][param].p)
        }
      }
}

var email = data.user; 
var subject = "your PDF extract";
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(REPORT_ID).getAs("application/pdf");

blob.setName("yourReport.pdf");

if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
   htmlBody: body,
   noReply:true,
   attachments:[blob]     
});  
}
```